# hadoop virtual machine file

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine

I am following tutorial on Getting Started With Hadoop on yahoo and as per the tutorial I am unable to extract Hadoop Virtual Machine zip folder.The file(hadoop-vm-appliance-0-18-0) is corrupted.Can anyone tell me where I can find it?

I tried from some other websites as well but it is corrupted there also.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from below link

https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/hadoop-0-20-virtual-machine-appliance-460.html

or

https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/distribution/